# How do I make a sitemap for a non-trivial and non-linear e-commerce web app?

Tags: sitemap

When I was researching how to do a sitemap, most of the examples I saw were for institutional websites. In my case, it's for an e-commerce web application that doesn't follow that same linearity.

Are there examples for complex sitemaps out there on which I could base my sitemap? Any reference websites?

Comment: *Why* would you make a sitemap for this app?

Comment: Do you mean sitemap as in what you create to create the site or sitemap as in the page some sites have?

Answer (score 4):

To my observation most popular eCommerce sites skip site map because of lot of interlinking between the pages.  check Amazon, http://www.oliveandmyrtle.com/, http://www.quikr.com/,  http://www.20north.com/, Rather they focus more on product classification and grouping, which make the user to understand where they are and what they want.  Also they make their help and FAQs better and monitored.

some of the examples of ecommerce site maps:

http://www.snapdeal.com/info/sitemap

http://www.volusion.com/ecommerce-web-design/

http://www.naaptol.com/sitemap.html

Answer (score 3):

What do you want the sitemap for? For your own piece of mind, so a user can look at it and decide where to go? The latter will happen in your taxonomy, which is why getting the taxonomy right in eCommerce is so important. Any eCommerce sitemap is going to be category and product listing specific.

Answer (score 2):

Create the full map first, then edit it with the user in mind. I've done this before for large-scale e-commerce sites. A typical first edit might be an inclusionary edit--mark off what you definitely want to include, like product categories, as others have said. Look at your processes, such as your shopping cart, and try to view them from a user's perspective. What points might they want to revisit? Then check with your coders to make sure that pointing to certain steps in the process won't create problems.

Answer (score 0):

A site map is a visual or textually organized model of a Web site's content that allows the users to navigate through the site to find the information they are looking for, just as a traditional geographical map helps people find places they are looking for in the real world.

There are many online tools are available that creates site map in simple steps.
u can see example of a e commerce website :
http://www.iipt.org.in/retail_store/index.php?route=information/sitemap